# Is it possible in uDig to use Features from map to create a profile in profile View?

Tags: udig

Its great to have the Profile View in uDig. The user can create a profile withe the profile Tool. Its required to create a line in the Map

[image]

I was wondering if there is a possibility to select a feature in the map and use the geometry to calculate the profile

[image]

Is there a chance to to so, How can I solve this requirement? is it possible to switch measurement unit and use the same is used for the distance tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to select a feature in any feature layer. Then in the layer view select the feature layer and the raster layer you want the profile for. 
If you then right click on it, the profile operation appears which takes the selected feature from the feature layer and creates the profile on the raster.

Comment: Awesome. It works but I had to convert my Layer from abstract type Geometry to LineString. The right mouse Operation is kind of a hidden feature because its only available if two layers are selected. Is there a chance to add a function that works on a "LineString" Layer an gives the users a list of potential raster layers to create a profile on.

Comment: And what about the Unit of Measurement (Meter vs. degree)? Any chance to configure this?